# How to prevent non-chroot user access to system files

Tags: centos, ftp, chroot

My FTP Server has 5 Users namely user01,user02,user03,user04,user05.

Shared Folder /home/ftpusers
 Inside the folder...

```
      /home/ftpusers/user01
      /home/ftpusers/user02
      /home/ftpusers/user03
      /home/ftpusers/user04
      /home/ftpusers/user05
```

#cat /etc/vsftpd/chroot_list

user01

user02

#
  user01 and user02 are inside the ChrootJail,and its working fine.
 But user03,user04,user05 are not inside the chrootjail, **they can access any folder inside the system(Even /root or /etc)**.

but i want **user03 user04 user05 can only access  /home/ftpusers directory,not all the system files**...

Any solution..?

Comment: it helps if you show what research or troubleshooting you've attempted so far, and where exactly you're stuck

Answer (score 0):

Set user_config_dir and create configuration for each user in that directory. For example: /etc/vsftpd_users/user03. In user03 file set local_root variable to /home/ftpusers.

Comment: Not Working ya.. Here is the config file...
[root@web01 vsftpd]# egrep -v "^#|^$" vsftpd.conf
anonymous_enable=no
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
dual_log_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
xferlog_std_format=YES
ftpd_banner=Welcome to Web Solutions
chroot_list_enable=YES
chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd/chroot_list
listen=YES
pam_service_name=vsftpd

userlist_enable=YES

tcp_wrappers=YES

use_localtime=YES

user_config_dir=/etc/vsftpd/users
____________________________________
 $cat /etc/vsftpd/users/user01

  local_root=/home/ftpusers

Comment: What platform are you using? I have the same config in debian/ubuntu, but only without chroot_list_file and with slash after directory paths

Comment: You're great! Now Working Two Changes I Made 1)slash after the directory path 2) Uncommented chroot_local_user=YES